# How to use ajax post request response data to make another ajax post request?

Tags: json, ajax, post, .post

I need to make two ajax post request to an api url.The first request returns some data as json (password,session,sessionId,itemId).

could any one show me how i can grab password,session,sessionId,itemId values and use it to make another ajax post request to the same api url ?

My current code only gets api response but how to use value of password,session,sessionId,itemId in the second post request ?

I tried to reference the api data like this data.keys.password, data.keys.session ,data.items.seasonId , data.items.itemId and I get error data.keys and data.items are undefined!

Could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

(Note:Currently i put the data in second post request hardcoded for demo purpose)

ajax post request call:

```
function callAjax() {


        $.post("https://api-somewebsite.com/process.aspx",
        {
          name: "galaxy",
          itemNum: "123456789"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            // now i want to use api response data to make another ajax post call
             $.post("https://api-somewebsite.com/process.aspx",
             {
               password: "2342432423ledf",
               session: "23isaofdfjosidfiedfdd=="
               seasonId: "12345",
              itemId:    "334455"
             },
            function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);


             });

        });


};

<br>
<button onclick="callAjax()">callAjax</button>
```

api response(for first ajax post request) that i want to reference its items:

```
{
     "keys": {
         "password": "2342432423ledf",
         "session": "23isaofdfjosidfiedfdd=="
     },
     "items": {
         "seasonID": 12345,
         "itemID": 334455,
}

}
```

Comment: What happens when you replace the hard coded data in the inner POST request with the "data" variable from the first request's success function? Looks like that would work to make the second request work.

Comment: Thanks for replys. I tried to use data,keys.password and data.keys.session but all give me undefined!

Comment: What does `data` (from the first request) look like when you alert/log it?

Comment: i have posted the first api response in my first post, looks like this :{
     "keys": {
         "password": "2342432423ledf",
         "session": "23isaofdfjosidfiedfdd=="
     },
     "items": {
         "seasonID": 12345,
         "itemID": 334455,
}

}

Comment: If that's `data`, then `data.keys.session` isn't undefined. Your call to `$.post` looks fine.

Comment: i tried to alert data.keys.session but i get data.keys undefined ! I want to use that value in my second post request instead of hard coding! How to use those values inside second post request ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103399/discussion-between-dsilver1221-and-user1788736).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We resolved the issue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103399/discussion-between-dsilver1221-and-user1788736).

The first request doesn't have the **Content-Type** header set to JSON, so the response isn't getting parsed. Setting `dataType` to `json` (the last argument to `$.post`) correctly sets the header and the response will be parsed as JSON. This means that `data` is an object, whose properties can be accessed, rather than a string.

Answer (score -1):

I think below code may help you

```
function callAjax() {


    $.post("https://api-somewebsite.com/process.aspx",
            {
                name: "galaxy",
                itemNum: "123456789"
            },
            function(data,status){
      //return the data as json_encode(yourvalue); from process.aspx 
                console.log(data);
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);                   

            });

       };
```

Comment: This looks like you had just taken the example response the OP gave as an example and provided as the data in the follow up request. The second request should use the actual `data` object to find what it needs to provide in the payload. Currently this answer gives a hard-coded value, rather than the actual response form the first request.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, did you even read the question?

"How to use ajax post request response data to make another ajax post request?"